# VAST/VPAID ads patterns and the amp-video tag

Tags: ads, vast, amp-html

Please, someone would know how can I use the vast / vpaid advertisement patterns with the amp-video tag?

I would like to use the vast pattern delivered by the ad-server to display ads before video content.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't support for this functionality but please create a new issue: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new to start a conversation about adding support for the Video Ad Serving Template technology: http://www.iab.com/guidelines/digital-video-ad-serving-template-vast-3-0/

Take a look at existing relevant issues and clarify how your needs differ:
- https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/958 "Support for pre-roll video ads"
- https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/71 "Adding a preroll attribute to the amp-video component"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the amp-ima-video tag: https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-ima-video/

This tag wasn't available when question was originally posted.